# Why isn't my component displaying in Digital Experiences?

Tags: component, digital-experience

Why isn't my component displaying in Digital Experiences?

Below is the component code, this displays in a regular page layout in LEX but not in Digital Experiences. I do not see any errors. I checked security on the apex class (I added everyone to it to avoid any issues). The component doesn't accesses any objects so I am not worried that it can't access specific object. What am I missing?

```
<aura:component implements="forceCommunity:availableForAllPageTypes,flexipage:availableForRecordHome,force:hasRecordId" access="global" controller="CaptureLastParent">  
    <aura:handler name="init" value="{!this}" action="{!c.init}"></aura:handler> 
</aura:component>
```

Comment: what template have you choosen?

Comment: I see a note in the docs about including a design part of the component and it looks like it might get its label from there.  Have you set a design file?
example from docs:
<design:component label="Hello World">
    <design:attribute name="subject" label="Subject" description="Name of the person you want to greet" />
    <design:attribute name="greeting" label="Greeting" />
</design:component>

Comment: @MohithShrivastava - it says "Customer Service"